# Warning: include(KiTT.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.8.1.0, magento-1.9.3.2

I am trying to upgrade a Magento installation from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.3.2. I have followed the guide on [Upgrade Roadmap for Magento Community Edition (CE) 1.8 or 1.9](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_ce18_upgrade-roadmap.html) and I am now checking if the system is working as intended.

I get the following error in apache error log when going to the root path of the shop. [Klarna Payment extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/klarna-payment-extension-1.html) is a module that implements Klarna payment for the Magento installation.

```
[Tue May 23 14:45:59.183592 2017] [:error] [pid 14798] [client 111.222.333.444:55470] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'KiTT' not found in /path_to_magento_shop/app/code/community/Klarna/KlarnaPaymentModule/Helper/Api.php on line 83
```

The `KiTT` library is present in `lib/`:

```
$ find lib -maxdepth 1 -ls | grep KiTT
3148215    4 dr-xr-x---  10 myuser www-data     4096 Mar  9 13:32 lib/KiTT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an easy one... The directory `lib/KiTT` was present, but `lib/KiTT.php` was missing. Silly...